# Sometimes System() function in C gives sh error

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, system

If I use the system command especially in a if statement. For some reason it gives me a error saying `sh: line 1: "command": command not found`. Here is the code that does it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void run(bool a) {
  if (a) {
    // do something
  }
  else {
    system("gcc");
  }
}
int main() {
  run(false);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Here I am calling gcc and the error is `sh: line 1: gcc: command not found`. I don't know what to do about it. If i give `system("/usr/bin/gcc")`. It works, but it's not going to be the same for systems like Windows.

I was expecting to get this:

```bash
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Looks like `/usr/bin` isn't in your `$PATH`.

Comment: As an aside, don't write `if (a == true)` when `a` is a `bool`.  It's awkward and misleading.  Just write `if (a)`.

Comment: If you are using for example gcc/Mingw, then in order to call it from anywhere, you must manually tweak the environment variable PATH. As foretold in the Mingw installation instructions and FAQ.

Comment: But question 1 here is: have you installed gcc? Which version? Also the answer to getting gcc running in Linux and doing the same in Windows are entirely different ones. Linux typically comes with some semi-outdated flavour of gcc pre-installed. Windows has no clue what gcc is until you manually install it.

Comment: Listen, I am using Arch Linux. And GCC is preinstalled.

Comment: Here is the version if you are curious.

Comment: gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: And where is the output of $PATH: /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin /usr/bin/site_perl /usr/bin/vendor_perl /usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: So, The main point is that I have a function that first of all checks if GCC is available or not. If it is, then it is going to run GCC system command. The problem only occurs after I run the function that checks if GCC is available or not. But I can't even show you the function because it's too long and it overflows the comment section!

Comment: Here is the function in just a single line:

Comment: `b8 is_gcc_available() { i8 *p = getenv("PATH"); i8 *t = NULL;  #if defined(_WIN32) t = strtok(p, ";"); #else t = strtok(p, ":"); #endif DIR *d; struct dirent *e; while (t != NULL) { d = opendir(t); e = readdir(d); while (e != NULL) { if (e->d_name[0] == 'g') { #if defined(_WIN32) if (strcmp(e->d_name, "gcc.exe") == 0) { return true; } #else if (strcmp(e->d_name, "gcc") == 0) { return true; } #endif } e = readdir(d); } #if defined(_WIN32) t = strtok(0, ";"); #else t = strtok(0, ":"); #endif } closedir(d); return false; }`

Comment: GCC is NOT preinstalled on Arch Linux.

Comment: Ok, I have installed it by installing the `base-devel` package group.

Comment: I did it when i installed Arch, but what is the problem with the system() function?

Comment: Might be a language issue, but when you start a comment with “Listen,”, to me it sounds very rude. Being rude here generally makes people not want to help.

Comment: Sorry for the rudeness. I shall show sympathy to everyone next time. I apologize.